# Trying to escape null properties in json, but still getting "TypeError: json.outcome_status is undefined"

Tags: javascript, json

First of all sorry for asking this very common question, but I can't fix this error. I have some properties with null value. The property is `json[i].outcome_status.category` and the goal is to count the number of occurrence of each category in the json structure, without the null property of category. I am trying to escape it with:

```
if(json[i].outcome_status.category != null)
```

However, I'm still getting an error that is saying that the property is null. Here is my code:

```
<!--Load the AJAX API-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

// Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['table']});

// Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var jsonData = $.ajax({
      url: "getData.php",
      dataType:"json",
      async: false
      }).responseText;
   var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        dataTable.addColumn('string','category');
        dataTable.addColumn('string','context');
        dataTable.addColumn('number','id');
        dataTable.addColumn('string','location_subtype');
        dataTable.addColumn('string','location_type');
        dataTable.addColumn('string','month');
        dataTable.addColumn('string','persistent_id');
        dataTable.addColumn('string','street name');
        dataTable.addColumn('string','outcome status');

        json=JSON.parse(jsonData);
        var counter = 0;
        var countAntiSocial = 0;
        var countBurglary = 0;
        var countCriminal = 0;
        var countDrugs = 0;
        var countOtherTheft = 0;
        var countPublicDisorder = 0;
        var countRobbery = 0;
        var countShoplifting = 0;
        var countVehicleCrime = 0;
        var countViolentCrime = 0;
        var countOtherCrime = 0;
    for (var i=0; i<json.length; i++) {
        var row = [];       
        row.push(json[i].category);
        row.push(json[i].context);
        row.push(json[i].id);
        row.push(json[i].location_subtype);
        row.push(json[i].location_type);
        row.push(json[i].month);
        row.push(json[i].persistent_id);
        row.push(json[i].location.street.name);
        row.push(json[i].outcome_status ? json[i].outcome_status.category : "null");
        dataTable.addRow(row);
                    //escaping the nulls
        if(json[i].outcome_status.category != null) {
            if(json.outcome_status.category == "anti-social-behavior"){
                countAntiSocial = countAntisocial + 1;
            }

            if(json[i].outcome_status.category == "burglary"){
                countBurglary = countBurglary + 1
            }

            if(json[i].outcome_status.category == "criminal-damage-arson"){
                countCriminal = countCriminal + 1;
            }

            if(json[i].outcome_status.category == "drugs"){
                countDrugs = countDrugs + 1;
            }

            if(json[i].outcome_status.category == "other-theft"){
                countOtherTheft = countOtherTheft + 1;
            }

            if(json[i].outcome_status.category == "public-disorder-weapons"){
                countPublicDisorder = countPublicDisorder + 1;
            }

            if(json[i].outcome_status.category == "robbery"){
                countRobbery = countRobbery + 1;
            }

            if(json[i].outcome_status.category == "shoplifting"){
                countShopLifting = countShopLifting + 1;
            }

            if(json[i].outcome_status.category == "vehicle-crime"){
                countVehicleCrime = countVehicleCrime + 1;
            }

            if(json[i].outcome_status.category == "violent-crime"){
                countViolentCrime = countViolentCrime + 1;
            }

            if(json[i].outcome_status.category == "other-crime"){
                countOtherCrime = countOtherCrime + 1;
                alert(countOtherCrime);
            }
        }
    }
        var chart = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(dataTable, {width: 1000, height: 300});

}          
</script>
```

and my PHP:

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents('http://data.police.uk/api/crimes-street/all-crime?lat=52.629729&lng=-1.131592&date=2013-01'); 
$json = str_replace("\xe2\x80\xa8", '\\u2028', $json);
$json = str_replace("\xe2\x80\xa9", '\\u2029', $json);
echo $json;
?>
```

If anyone could spot what's the mistake, that would be appreciated. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `json[i].outcome_status` is undefined, then you're attempting to access a property of that. There is no `category` property to have a value, because the object you expect the property to exist on doesn't exist itself.

You handle that here:

```
row.push(json[i].outcome_status ? json[i].outcome_status.category : "null");
```

since that code is essentially: If `json[i].outcome_status` is not undefined, return its category, otherwise return the string `"null"`.

However, you don't handle it two lines down here:

```
if(json[i].outcome_status.category != null) {
```

That should be:

```
if(json[i].outcome_status != null && json[i].outcome_status.category != null)
```

Essentially, if it has an outcome status and that has a property category that's a truthful value, do the code inside.

Comment: Yeah, but since the `outcome_status` is defined into the json url and it also has a property `category`, then why I can't access it via `json[i].outcome_status.category`? I tried the last line of code, but I still get `TypeError: json.outcome_status is undefined`.

Comment: @AndreUk13 You can't access it using `json[i].outcome_status.category` because `json[i].outcome_status` **is undefined**. For at least one of the objects in that array **there is no `outcome_status` property**.

Comment: Fixed now! Btw, do you know a more efficient way of counting the number of occurrences in the `outcome_status.category`? As you can see I have 8 if statements to count each category. Is there any other more efficient way to do it? Thanks again.

Comment: @AndreUk13 You could use an empty object: `var counts = {}`, then use the value of `json[i].outcome_status.category` as a key to set the count. Something like this: http://pastebin.com/nmXZyVy1

Answer (score 0):

Try

`if(!!json[i].outcome_status.category) {`

the not-not clause is very handy!

Edit:

`row.push((!!json[i].outcome_status && !!json[i].outcome_status.category) ? json[i].outcome_status.category : "null");`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm still getting the error mate. I don't know if it's because of the format of the data

Comment: Ah yes, you might want to try adding that a couple of lines above: row.push((!!json[i].outcome_status && !!json[i].outcome_status.category) ? json[i].outcome_status.category : "null");

Comment: You mean instead of `row.push(json[i].outcome_status ? json[i].outcome_status.category : "null");` to put`row.push((!!json[i].outcome_status && !!json[i].outcome_status.category) ? json[i].outcome_status.category : "null");` ?